# Datframe adding Numpy array as many rows to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, rows

I'm using Numpy to calculate somme formulas.
I need a datafrale results with more details.

I tried something like `df_append.append` to load data in dataframe.

```
df_cars = pd.DataFrame(data= None,['CarName', "ModelName",'Month', 'values'])

for(carname in cars):
    modelsnames = getModels(car)
    for(modelname in Models):
        values=np.array(get_values(car,model))
        #values = [1,5,6,9,10,2,10,7,23,90,102,14]
        new_row={'CarName' :carname ,"ModelName": modelname, 'Month':np.arange(1,len(index)+1), 'value':index}
        df_cars = df_cars.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

But numpy values save it in one cell(results of Numpy formula)

Example:

numpy values_BMW_Serie1 : [45000,44000,41000,45000,42000]

```
   Car   Model    Month  value
1  BMW   Serie1   1       [45000,44000,41000,45000,42000]
```

I need to save each numpy value in one cell

```
   Car   Model    Month  value
1  BMW   Serie1   1       45000
2  BMW   Serie1   2       44000
3  BMW   Serie1   3       41000
4  BMW   Serie1   4       45000
5  BMW   Serie1   5       42000
```

Comment: cars  is a list of cars names like  cars['BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Kia'....] ; the subjet it how to append many rows to dataframe from numpy array

Comment: You can use `df_cars = df_cars.explode('value')`. However, why are you looping to populate your dataframe instead of dumping all the data and filtering once it is part of the df? this way you bypass the loops and the many calls to `getModels` and `get_values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fixe your problem, use the `explode()` function:

```
import numpy as np

df_cars=df_cars.explode('value')

df_cars.index = np.arange(1, len(df_cars) + 1)

df_cars['Month']=df_cars.index
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   Car   Model  Month  value
1  BMW  Serie1      1  45000
2  BMW  Serie1      2  44000
3  BMW  Serie1      3  41000
4  BMW  Serie1      4  45000
5  BMW  Serie1      5  42000
```

You can read more about `explode()` function on [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: Does it answer you? If it is, accept it to close the question.

Comment: but i have the same value in the "Month" column?i can't explode many columns. i 'am looking for fix it